# Apache or nginx: for 10 requests a second on a tiny server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, web-server, nginx

What would you recommend for a small server setup, maybe 10 requests a second (using php and mysql, dynamic content)?

Comment: Belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: Define "request" in this context. What content are you serving?

Answer (score 3):

I'd set up nginx as a reverse proxy for Apache. Let nginx handle all the static files (images, CSS, JavaScript) and `proxy_pass` off all the PHP stuff to Apache.

Comment: Is it possible to proxy all the PHP traffic to multiple servers?

Comment: Sure, you could. No need for 10 requests a second, though.

Comment: +1, 10 reqs/s is fairly low, as in: apache itself could handle it easily. Nothing wrong with thinking about the future however, and getting nginx in there _before_ there are performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about load,apache is older project, and has more examples on internet if 
later you need to do something more complicated.

Things like proxying, load sharing etc are for setups that have thousands of requests / second. For your needs they will only make things more complicated.

Comment: The server we are running is not a typical setup, very low powered.

Comment: i've been running whole ISP 10 years ago on 750mhz server with apache and php, so I guess you would be fine with few reqs/sec

Answer (score 0):

nginx with FastCGI. Don't go the Apache route unless you really need to use .htaccess files and are too lazy to convert them to nginx format, especially for a very low powered server (I'm guessing VPS)